# How do I remove a game off steam that doesn't give the the option when I right click

Tags: steam

The game "No more room in hell" will not show the option to remove when I right click on it. I installed the game through Desura quite some time ago and it put it in my steam library but now I want it out of there. Any idea of how I can do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since it's a mod residing in Steam's `steamapps\sourcemods` folders (see [here](http://www.nomoreroominhell.com/faq/154)), either delete that folder (probably `nmrih`, automatically also removing the Steam entry) or use Desura again to uninstall it there, which also should remove the Steam entry and folder.

In case the folder cannot be entirely deleted despite Steam being closed (e.g. Windows may claim you need Administrator permissions even though you have them), use the tool [unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/). Thanks @galacitninja for [mentioning that](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/123258/how-do-i-remove-a-game-off-steam-that-doesnt-give-the-the-option-when-i-right-c/123261?noredirect=1#comment166566_123261)

Comment: I found the folder but when I try to delete it it tells me that "You require permission from administrators to make changes to this folder" I would delete it on desura but it does not work for me anymore. I have reinstalled it, repaired it and things like that but it just wont work.

Comment: Doesn't it ask you to grant these admin permissions? Ok, in that case click on the start menu, enter `explorer`, right click on the windows explorer and select "run as administrator". Then you should be able to delete the folder

Comment: It deleted everything except the folder for Models. It tells me the same message about administrator privileges even though I ran explorer as administrator.

Comment: Do you still have Steam running? Close it while you're deleting this folder, this cryptic message may be due to that

Comment: Nope, steam was closed.

Comment: Strange. You could try rebooting your PC (maybe even in safe mode), maybe Steam put a broken file lock somewhere. If that also doesn't work, you might best want to ask a separate question like "Why can I not delete a specific folder even as administrator" over at http://superuser.com

Comment: @Dahbestguy Try using [Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/) to delete it.

Comment: @Zommuter Restarting did not work for me, but Unlocker did and now No more room in hell is gone from my steam library. Thank you very much for all the help.

Comment: You're welcome (also thanks @galacticninja, I once more forgot about that one awesome tool). Please accept this answer if helped you so others don't waste timing to try and find a different solution. Read more about accepting and voting [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/about), where you'll also get another shiny badge ;-) And, welcome to the ArQAde!